# Error when trying to build my Plutus project using nix-shell

Tags: cabal, nix-shell, development, build, ghc

I am getting the following error after running `cabal build` using `nix-shell`:

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: Win32-network (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: Win32-network-0.1.1.0/installed-Cm3H3JOsc0sL7v05D4U9jQ
(constraint from user target requires ==0.1.0.0)
[__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0
[__1] trying: base-4.14.3.0/installed-4.14.3.0 (dependency of Win32-network)
[__2] trying: lobemo-scribe-systemd-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__3] next goal: libsystemd-journal (dependency of lobemo-scribe-systemd)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.5 (conflict: pkg-config package
libsystemd>=209, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.4 (conflict:
base==4.14.3.0/installed-4.14.3.0, libsystemd-journal => base>=4.6 && <4.13)
[__3] skipping: libsystemd-journal-1.4.3, libsystemd-journal-1.4.2,
libsystemd-journal-1.4.1, libsystemd-journal-1.4.0, libsystemd-journal-1.3.4,
libsystemd-journal-1.3.3, libsystemd-journal-1.3.1, libsystemd-journal-1.3.0,
libsystemd-journal-1.2.0, libsystemd-journal-1.1.0, libsystemd-journal-1.0.0
(has the same characteristics that caused the previous version to fail:
excludes 'base' version 4.14.3.0)
[__3] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd, Win32-network
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

I am using `cabal 3.6.2.0` and `ghc 8.10.7`

Comment: The conflict suggests your ghc may be too new, try with 8.10.7

Comment: Hey James, thanks for your reply but that was actually a typo. I have just corrected the GHC version in the post.

Comment: In that case, try entering shell with `nix develop` as per the contributing doc: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

Comment: I am getting this error when I want to run `nix develop`: `error: flake 'git+file:///home/matifalcone/Blockchain/Cardano/Plutus/plutus-apps' does not provide attribute 'devShells.x86_64-linux.default', 'devShell.x86_64-linux', 'packages.x86_64-linux.default' or 'defaultPackage.x86_64-linux'`

Comment: Right, that's for `plutus` repo. For `plutus-apps` follow instructions in https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

Comment: Which instructions should I follow there? I don't see the `nix develop` option in this file.

Comment: You've not given much context so I don't know exactly what you were trying to build. If you're unable to build a project based on plutus-apps using the instructions in its contributing document then will need more details about what differences there are in your project.

Comment: This is the project I am trying to run: https://github.com/Falcon-Cardano-Stakepool/token-vesting-script

Comment: Rather than debugging this you should look at updating your dependencies within the last 6 months. Your targeting node 1.33.0 which is over a year old now and won't work on any current public testnet. Try target 1.35.4, as plutus-apps currently does, bring your index state and target commits a bit more up to date and it should make things easier.